# How to short certain pins on a 7x9 array

Tags: raspberry-pi

I’m planning to control an 80s electric typewriter via a Raspberry Pi. I want to emulate the keyboard matrix by shorting one of seven 5V pins to another one of nine that feed into a microcontroller. Eg, shorting pin 0 and 16 prints out a full stop; 5 and 12 print ‘w’ etc.

[image: pcb]

How can I best control this?

Comment: Does the keyboard have any [modifier keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key) that could complicate things? E.g. you might need to "press" shift *just* before another key to get the shifted character.

Comment: @AndrewMorton If you mean that the key is released before typing the next character, then no. If yes, then there's a shift key and a code key for centring  and foreign characters etc.

Comment: I've added a third option to my answer which is likely better than either other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the conceptually easy way, that would take as many elements as you have keys to emulate, and the trickier more efficient way.

Conceptually easy. Find out what voltage drop you can tolerate at each closure. Place a relay, or FET, or optocoupler output closure at each intersection that will give you less than this voltage drop. This is expensive in components, as not only do you need many 10s of switches, but you also have to control them from your Pi.

More efficient. The keys obviously belong to a multiplexed array. Take the row drive pins into your Pi, and drive one of the column pins at the right time, when the relevant row pin is active. Ideally you'll have an oscilloscope so you can see what's happening, and to debug any timing problems you run into. Potential timing problems are that your Pi will will not be able to respond instantly to a row drive going active. Your typewriter may tolerate this lateness, or may not. You may have to experiment with your column response timing.

A hybrid, which does not trouble the Pi for a fast response. Connect a multiplexer to the drive pins, and a demultiplexer to the response pins, and program their routing from the Pi. These will almost certainly respond fast enough. If they have sufficiently low resistance, then you could use analogue muxes like HC4051 to do both jobs.

Comment: also note that this second option is definitely something to gain engineer street cred, but also likely not easier than replacing the matrix controller altogether and directly talking to the printer. ("easier" is a very relative term – this might be super interesting for you, or hard, or neither, or both)

Comment: The third option is what I was looking for — thanks! Since the matrix is really inconvient insomuch as it has nine inputs, is there another IC that I could use with a greater number of inputs or perhaps is there a better option to wire this to the demultiplexer?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by sufficiently low resistance?

Comment: @Jacob Those analogue multiplexers have series resistance, of the order of 100 ohms. Your switch array will certainly work if you connect the pins with 10 ohms, and probably won't if you use 1 Meg. But where is the threshhold? There may be pullups on the receive side, of maybe 10k. So I'd not be surprised if 1k between the pins also worked, in which two multiplexers in series would be OK. But if the receiver load was heavier, a few hundred ohms to 'short' the pins might be too much. You'll need to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the large number of potential connections (in effect, as many as keys on your keyboard):

Get a lot of what are called "analog switches" (in the end: FETs as switches) in an IC – TI, for example, has [high-switch-count ICs](https://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/analog/products.html?pqs=paqs&familyid=520#p480=24;20;16&sort=p1130;asc), but I don't know how cheap they'll be in low quantity. Use e.g. shift registers to open/close them individually.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to use a similar row and column decoder used to scan each switch to detect the switch state in reverse and to drive the state of desired keys with a voltage source using a CMOS analog switch.

If the scanner is synchronized to the encoder then shared electronics could be used to drive the switch state with a single switch using the same parallel bus of the decoder.  Synchronization to simplify the encoder bus monitor of the keyboard decoder might use a special index pulse with a counter as it increments thru all the keys. This reduces to 3 signals. Index, clk and data switch.